# Problems with populating an array inside the Backbone model

Tags: javascript, arrays, backbone.js

I have the following code:

```js
handleNewFillupForm: function (parameters) {
   data.fillups.push(parameters);
    ...
}
```

*data* is a Bacbone model and *fillups* an array containing plain JS objects. *parameters* is such a simple JS object: {key:value, ...}. However, when I check for what has been inserted in *fillups* array, it's not this object but a fully blown Backbone model. I don't understand why this happens. How can I remedy this?

Comment: what does console.log of data.fillups give?

Comment: An array of JS objects that are fetched from the server. They are NOT Backbone models (as they shouldn't be). In the meantime I solved this issue (it was another part of the code that was executing actually).